# Nginx reverse proxy works only for landing page, any other links won't work

Tags: nginx, proxy

I have a reverse proxy for `/forums` setup like so:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name localhost;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }
        location /forums {
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

                proxy_pass      http://127.0.0.1:4567/;
                proxy_redirect off;

                # Sockect.IO Support
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        }
}
```

It works, kind of, when I try to go to `localhost/forums` I see the page, but all the static content 404's and if I try to click on a link, e.g. /login it takes me to `localhost/login` instead of `localhost/forums/login`, any idea how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You should add a slash character at the end of `location /forums` so as to get:

```
location /forums/ {
 ...
}
```

According to the doc:

> If a location is defined by a prefix string that ends with the slash
>   character, and requests are processed by one of proxy_pass then the
>   special processing is performed. In response to a request with URI
>   equal to this string, but without the trailing slash, a permanent
>   redirect with the code 301 will be returned to the requested URI with
>   the slash appended.